# How to get the LineNumber of the opening tag given the LineNumber of the closing tag

Tags: c#, xml

Given this sample xml node,

```
<employee id="emp_1">
    <fname>John</fname>
    <lname>Doe</lname>
</employee>
<supervisor>
    <fname>Jane</fname>
    <lname>Does</lname>
</supervisor>
```

i can use the two given variables:

```
lineNumber = 4;
colNumber = 12;
```

if i would locate the position, it will be right after the closing tag,

```
"</employee>"
```

is it possible to get/return the lineNumber of the corresponding opening tag of employee node?

please help.
Thanks

Comment: It is possible if you treat XML as plain text and write code accordingly...

Comment: Look first comment this is how you can do it with your requirements.

Comment: uhm, no. i still can't see how it will give me the linenumber of the opening tag

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the best way but after giving it much thought, i just decided to get the nextline which will give me the nextnode. then using the nextnode, i got the previous sibling.

```
//...previous codes
lineNumber++;
var nextSibling = xElements.Where(elem => ((IXmlLineInfo)elem).LineNumber == lineNumber &&
                                           ((IXmlLineInfo)elem).LinePosition <= columnNumber).LastOrDefault();

var selectedNode = nextSibling.PreviousNode;
if (((IXmlLineInfo)selectedNode).HasLineInfo())
{
    lineNumber = ((IXmlLineInfo)selectedNode).LineNumber;
    columnNumber = ((IXmlLineInfo)selectedNode).LinePosition;
}
```

now the lineNumber will be the lineNumber for the opening tag of employee node

Comment: What happens if there is space between each XElement?

Comment: that, i didn't handle yet, however for now, i just assumed that there will be no spaces between elements since i was also the one who created the method to generate the xml. but still this isn't the best solution though

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage XNode.CreateReader to re-parse current XElement. It requires more resource but does work.

```
foreach (XElement e in elements)
{
    using (var reader = e.CreateReader())
    {
        var lineInfo = ((IXmlLineInfo)reader);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.Depth == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{e.Name}"
                    + $" - Open({((IXmlLineInfo)e).LineNumber},{((IXmlLineInfo)e).LinePosition})"
                    + $" Close({lineInfo.LineNumber},{lineInfo.LinePosition})");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LinePosition is tag start position. You can calculate end position by + tag name length.